# Is there a framework or something else I have to download for android development to make connecting a bluetooth low energy device possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Im working on a simple Android application and need it to have the ability to connect to a Bluetooth low energy device.  Im relatively new to Android development and was wondering if there were any frameworks or SDKs that I had to download to make this possible.

Comment: Bluetooth LE is only supported in API 18 and greater. I'd take a look at [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to [Bluetooth Studio](http://www.bluetooth.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/developer-studio/bluetooth-developer-studio.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but it seems like Bluetooth Studios is more for development on the Bluetooth Chip side of things rather than the actually application development.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you should not need anything special to work with Bluetooth low energy on Android at long as you are targeting a platform that is API 18 or higher. An excellent place to start as mentioned in the comment above is the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). The other place I would look at for an example are the samples provided by Google. The BLE one can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html). Be warned though that devices with API 18 devices do support BLE, they had a lot of bugs, and you might be better of just supporting a minimum level of 19 (KitKat).